# Scroll bars in table cells

Tags: html, scrollbar, html-table

I want a table that takes up the entire screen that has a sidebar, bottom bar, and main panel. Each should be able to scroll independently, and in no case should the entire page have a scroll bar.

This is what I have:

```html
<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display:block;">
  <table style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 1px;">
    <tbody style="height:100%">
      <tr>
        <td id="sidebar" style="width: 200px; height: 100%; vertical-align: top;" rowspan="2">
          <div style="width: 200px;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x:auto;">
            Side
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="stepeditor" style="vertical-align: top; position: relative; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: scroll;">
            main
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; height: 200px; border-top: 1px solid;">
          <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: scroll;">
            bottom
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have been messing around with a lot of options, and currently only the sidebar works like I want, but there are still scroll bars on the full window, and I have no idea why they are there.

How do I get this to work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: https://jsfiddle.net/mj0baug5/

Instead of `overflow:auto` use `overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:scroll;` for each panel. This will enable vertical scrolling but not horizontal scrolling.

To restrict the page from scrolling use:

```
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem in styles.

For body need set margin:0;
For tbody do not need set height = 100%
Border in the table is also a problem it is better to move to the div (if border needed)

```
<style>
     html, body {padding: 0; margin:0;  width: 100%; height: 100%;}
</style>

<div style="width: 100%; height: 100%; display:block;">
  <table style="position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
    <tbody >
      <tr>
        <td id="sidebar" style="width: 200px; height: 100%; vertical-align: top;" rowspan="2">
          <div style="width: 200px;height: 100%;margin: 0;padding: 0;overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x:auto;">
            Side
          </div>
        </td>
        <td id="stepeditor" style="vertical-align: top; position: relative; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;">
          <div style="position: relative; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: scroll;">
            main
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top; height: 200px; border-top: 1px solid;">
          <div style="width: 100%; height: 200px; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow: scroll;">
            bottom
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```